# Помогите найти ответ

Tags: литература

Подскажите,пожалуйста, сколько же денег нашла Муха-Цокотуха по произведению К.Чуковского?

Answer (score 3):

Деньга - это полкопейки (1/200 рубля). По крайней мере, с 18 века принято было считать так.
Правда, не уверена, что на эти деньги можно было купить самовар (разве что "мушиных" размеров) )))